# JS edit CSS pixel value

Tags: javascript, html, css

My CSS:

```
.clip-circle {
  clip-path: circle(10px at center);
}
```

My HTML:

```
<img src="" alt="" class="clip-circle" id="pic" >
```

How do I edit the `px` value of clip-path whenever a button is pressed ?

JS :

```
function changeSize (button) {
  var pic = document.getElementById("pic");
  pic.style.WhatDoIWriteHere = "??";
}
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The property is called `clipPath`. I haven't found the documentation, but it is quite common that the style property is the same as in CSS just without the hyphen and in camelCase (just like `backgroundColor`).

```js
var pic = document.getElementById("pic");

pic.addEventListener('click', e => {
  e.target.style.clipPath = "circle(20px at center)";
});
```

```css
.clip-circle {
  clip-path: circle(10px at center);
}
```

```html
<img src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB2aWV3Qm94PSIwIDAgMTAwIDEwMCIgeG1sbnM9Imh0dHA6Ly93d3cudzMub3JnLzIwMDAvc3ZnIj4KICA8cmVjdCB3aWR0aD0iMTAwIiBoZWlnaHQ9IjEwMCIgZmlsbD0iYmx1ZSIgLz4KPC9zdmc+" width="100" height="100" alt="" class="clip-circle" id="pic">
```